# How to make a checkbox checked dynamically after passing a value from another component in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, angular6

My second.html:

```
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"> 
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkmark" name="nond" [checked]="r=='true'"  (change)="nond($event, check)">
          </div>
```

My second.ts:

```
   Flag(): void {
this._call.getflag()
  .subscribe(r => {
    this.Flag = r;
    let value = true;
    if (r == value) {
      let data = {
        'flag': r
      };
      let obj = this.$modal.show(DComponent, undefined, data)
        .subscribe(r => {
          if (r.click === 'CONTINUE') {
            obj.unsubscribe();
          }
        });
    }

  });
}
```

I have a checkbox in this html page. In my typescript file, on initialize, Im calling an API function & it will return a boolean value. Based on that I need to check my checkbox & should pass the checked value. So can anybody please tell me how to do this in angular 6?

Comment: I don't completely get your code here, but now you are checking if r == *string* `true` not boolean. If you want it checked when `r` is boolean `true`, just do: `[checked]="r"`. But I don't understand where `r` is even coming from :D

Answer (score 0):

If your "r" is a boolean variable then you don't even need to use [checked]

**don't need below**

```
[checked]="r=='true'"  (change)="nond($event, check)"
```

**Instead do like this**

```
<button (click)="changeCheckBoxStatus(true)">Check</button>
<button (click)="changeCheckBoxStatus(false)">Uncheck</button>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkmark" name="nond" [ngModel]="checkboxStatus" (ngModelChange)="checkBoxStatus($event)"> checkBox
```

**component**

```
export class CheckBoxComponent {
  checkboxStatus = true;

  checkBoxStatus(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.checkboxStatus = event;
  }

  changeCheckBoxStatus(status: boolean) {
    this.checkboxStatus = status;
  }
}
```

**Note:**
If you use (change) event, it will trigger only when user physically clicks the checkbox and it won't trigger when you update checkbox status from you component

Comment: Thank you so much. But my problem now is r is not returning boolean variable. r gives {click: "CONTINUE"} this value in my console.